# How can I get my code to show in dreamweaver same as firefox and Ie

Tags: php, html, mysql, tooltip

Mysql, Bootstrap, Tooltips and I am trying to further my abilities so I thought what better way to learn than to jump rite in.

I have found many answers to my questions on this and other sites but as my project gets more complicated it is getting harder to find answers.

I wrote this script and it appears to function perfectly (exactly how I wanted it to), in Firefox and IE, but for some reason inside Dreamweaver's live feature it is showing some of the Php where it should not be. It is as if there is an error. But again Firefox and IE are not showing errors, in fact everything is working perfectly in the browsers.
Here is the code I am working with.

Perhaps my code is just sloppy, as you can see I go in and out of PHP too much.
So in Dreamweaver two bullet points and the code snip-it  :
Member logged in and active.
this is what is showing in my Dreamweaver when I select live.

:
= "2") { echo $hours; ?> Hours, Minutes Minutes

I am not sure why that code is showing it should not be in the live version.

I could learn so much from anyone willing to help. Thank you.

```
<?php

include("db.php");

$con=mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pwd) //connect to the database server
or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_name)  //select the database
or die ("Could not select to mysql because ".mysql_error());

#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$time = time(); #Current time 
$previous = "86400"; #Time to check in seconds (24 hours)
$logout = $time-$previous; #Timeout=time - 24hours 


# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$time1 = time(); #Current time 
$previous1 = "600"; #Time to check in seconds  
$lagout1 = $time1-$previous1; #Timeout=time - 10 minutes 

#/////////////////////////loggedin AND lagged in //////////////////////////////

//prevent sql injection
//$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
//$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE logout > \"$logout\" AND lagout >
    \"$lagout1\" ORDER BY username ASC";                                                 
$online = mysql_query($query); #Execute query 
$row_online = mysql_fetch_assoc($online); #Grab the users 

if (isset($row_online['username'])) { #If there is atleast one user online 
do { #Do this 

?>

<div id="effect2" >

<li><a href="#"><?php echo $row_online['username']; ?></a><span><?php echo             $row_online['username']; ?>:<br /><font color='yellow'>Member logged in and active.        </font></span></li>

</div>      

<? 

}    while($row_online = mysql_fetch_assoc($online)); #Until all records are displayed 

} 

?>

<?
#//////////////////Logged in BUT lagged out//////////////////////////////// 

$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE logout > \"$logout\" AND lagout <     \"$lagout1\" ORDER BY username ASC "; #Check and see who is online in the last 2 minutes 
$online = mysql_query($query); #Execute query 
$row_online = mysql_fetch_assoc($online); #Grab the users 

if (isset($row_online['username'])) { #If there is atleast one user online 
do { #Do this 

?>

<?
$T = time();
$lagT = $row_online['logout'];
$S = $T - $lagT;
$init = $S;
$hours = floor($init / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($init / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $init % 60;
?>

<div id="effect2" >

<li><a href="#"><font color='#333333'><?php echo $row_online['username']; ?></font>    </a><span><?php echo $row_online['username']; ?>:<br />

Idle for: <font color='red'>
<? if ($hours == "1") {

echo  $hours; ?> Hour, <? echo $minutes; ?> Minutes 
</font></span></li> 

<? }elseif ($hours >= "2") {

echo $hours; ?> Hours, <? echo $minutes; ?> Minutes
</font></span></li> 

<? } elseif ($hours <= "1") {

echo $minutes;  ?> Minutes
</font></span></li> 

<? } ?>
</div>

<?

} while($row_online = mysql_fetch_assoc($online)); #Until all records are displayed

} 

?>



<div style="position: absolute; 10px;  center: 14px; top: 286px; 90px; top: 294px;   left: 10px;">


 <?
#////////////////////////////////////  there are no more members online ///////////////
echo "_________________________<br /><center>Members who have logged <br />off do not show on this list.</center>"; #Inform user that no one is online 


?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does using the full `<?php … ?>` tags instead of the short-tags (`<? … ?>`) help?